# Tunnelling RTSP through HTTP

Tags: http, rtsp, bada

I need to send video stream between 2 mobile devices. Bada has no support for rtsp so i found its possible to tunnel it through http. can someone help me out with a sample on how to start of. Im new to bada application development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bada has no RTSP *per se*, but it has sockets - `Osp::Net::Sockets::Socket`. I think your best bet is studying the description of RTSP and reimplementing it by hand over sockets. Since the bada sockets are not the same as POSIX sockets in terms of API (although I'm pretty sure bada sockets are a thin layer on top of POSIX ones), it's unlikely you'll find a ready made open source RTSP library.